# Can't answer protected question though I have 101 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, protected-questions

[How should a parent advise a child who wants to become a musician even though he is devoid of talent?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/22030/how-should-a-parent-advise-a-child-who-wants-to-become-a-musician-even-though-he)

This question doesn't seem to let me answer. I know it's protected, but I have 101 rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the site.

This is a common question on all the sites. Site wide, one must earn 10 reputation on the *specific site* you wish to post an answer on. *The 100 point association bonus doesn't count toward the rep needed to answer a protected question.*

The [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) is addressed on Meta.SE:

> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to answer a protected question.

Comment: Ok! Makes sense, thanks. What good is the 100 then. :)

Comment: The text in the in-page protection message across all SE sites certainly appears to imply that it's based on the literal reputation score, and not on activity specific to the current site; I do wish it would be reworded to be more explicit about the association bonus not counting, or in other words that it refers to rep earned **through interactions on this site** particularly.

Comment: @Almo It does [grant _some_ privileges](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) (e.g. vote up, chat, participate in meta). Just not all of them ;)